# Double whitespaces, break lines, tabs, removed when moving to source to editor

Tags: ckeditor

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

If you are on "Source" mode and you add two whitespaces then you go back to the editor it removes it, same with break lines and tabs. Is there any way i can preserve this when i move from the source to the editor?

You can do the test on the ckeditor demo itself:

[image: Before]

[image: AFter]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just how HTML works - it will collapse your white space (space, tab, new line) characters down to a single space.

If you really want to use multiple spaces, use non-breaking spaces, just put `&nbsp;` for each space you want to get.